# OpenCV 2.4.5 & Boost for Passing VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv, boost

Issue: Want to pass cv::VideoCapture objects into a different thread. I want to be able to dynamically handle how many cameras I can have.

Proposed Solution: Insert into a vector and pass as argument into Thread:

Inserting mechanism:

```
std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<cv::VideoCapture> > CamVect;
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    boost::shared_ptr<cv::VideoCapture> cvInputObj(new cv::VideoCapture(i));
    if((*cvInputObj.get()).isOpened()){
        CamVect.push_back(cvInputObj);
        ValidCams++;
    }
}
```

Retrieval Mechanism:Create local vector and assign passed in data to that vector as such:

```
cVision::cVision(std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<cv::VideoCapture> > CamVect)
{
    Cameras=CamVect;
}
```

Following this I go ahead and do the following to pull out the image:

Note, some typedefs for the below:

```
typedef std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<cv::VideoCapture> > CameraContainer;
typedef CameraContainer::iterator CamIterator;
```

Using this, I create an iterator and try to retrieve the images. From what I gathered from the [class definition](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) the '>>' operator just does a grab() followed by a retrieve()

```
void cVision::grabImage(int CamNumber){
int index=0;
for(CamIterator it=Cameras.begin();it!=Cameras.end();++it)
{
    if(index==CamNumber) {
        if((*it)->grab()) {
            cout<<"Successfully grabbed!"<<endl;
            if((*it)->retrieve(imCur[CamNumber],0))
                cout<<"Successfully retrieved!"<<endl;
            else
                cout<<"Error retrieving"<<endl;
        }
    } else index++;
}
}
```

Issue: It seems like it is successfully calling the grab() method, but fails on the retrieve? (this is my guess):

```
libv4l2: error dequeuing buf: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_DQBUF: Invalid argument
Successfully grabbed!
```

Any advice will be immensely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to circumvent this. I.e. by defining the following as a global from main():

```
std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<cv::VideoCapture> > CamVect;
```

Following this I just called the same method from the thread and it worked as expected.

Still not sure why this happened though.